# Call stack size within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I want to test for large call stacks. Specifically, I want a console warning when the call stack length reaches 1000. This usually means I did something stupid, and can lead to subtle bugs.

Can I compute the call stack length within JavaScript?

Comment: Does [this](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) help?

Comment: The code Dave Newton points to throws an exception, catches it as `e` and inspects its properties, based on the browser. For Chrome and Mozilla, it uses `e.stack`, for Opera 10+ it uses `e.stacktrace` and for others it will try to make sense of the `e.message` property.

Comment: Doesn't the error stack trace only give up to 10 stack entries? http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AuyP7/

Comment: in some cases you could use `console.trace()`

Comment: It's not generally possible to do this without `arguments.callee` or `caller`. See my revised answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton Note that because of its age it targets Opera and IE's old JavaScript engines, and at least in Opera's case all these properties have radically changed.

Comment: Stack overflow bugs are hardly subtle...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's a function that will work in all major browsers, although it won't work in ECMAScript 5 strict mode because `arguments.callee` and `caller` have been removed in strict mode.

```
function getCallStackSize() {
    var count = 0, fn = arguments.callee;
    while ( (fn = fn.caller) ) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Example:

```
function f() { g(); }       
function g() { h(); }       
function h() { alert(getCallStackSize()); }       

f(); // Alerts 3
```

**UPDATE 1 November 2011**

In ES5 strict mode, there is simply [no way to navigate the call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript). The only option left is to parse the string returned by `new Error().stack`, which is non-standard, not universally supported and obviously problematic, and even this [may not be possible for ever](http://whereswalden.com/2010/09/08/new-es5-strict-mode-support-now-with-poison-pills/).

**UPDATE 13 August 2013**

This method is also limited by the fact that a function that is called more than once in a single call stack (e.g. via recursion) will throw `getCallStackSize()` into an infinite loop (as pointed out by @Randomblue in the comments). An improved version of `getCallStackSize()` is below: it keeps track of functions it has seen before to avoid going into an infinite loop. However, the returned value is the number of different function objects in the callstack before encountering a repeat rather than the true size of the complete call stack. This is the best you can do, unfortunately.

```
var arrayContains = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(arr, val) {
        return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;
    } :
    function(arr, val) {
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

function getCallStackSize() {
    var count = 0, fn = arguments.callee, functionsSeen = [fn];

    while ( (fn = fn.caller) && !arrayContains(functionsSeen, fn) ) {
        functionsSeen.push(fn);
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Just in case anyone experiences this problem: in Chrome's Developer Tools it alerts `6` but that's because there are seemingly 3 other functions being executed behind the scenes when using the Console.

Comment: nice one! so, in ES5 strict mode, they decided that the callstack is too dangerous ? maybe this is only to prevent alterations of the callstack's default behaviour..

Comment: @Fred arguments.caller/arguments.callee becomes fun when you want to do function inlining and tail-call optimization (which is mandatory in ES.next).

Comment: This does not work for call stacks with loops. The function `getCallStackSize` does not return in that case.

Comment: @Randomblue: Example script?

Comment: @Randomblue: Good point. The problem is that a function object only has one `caller` property, so if a function has called itself then its `caller` property is a reference to itself and hence the `while` loop never exits. You could check for this by comparing `fn` to `fn.caller` (http://jsfiddle.net/3DNUw/2/) but the call stack size returned is no longer accurate. Also, this does not deal with the case when chains of functions are called recursively (http://jsfiddle.net/3DNUw/3/). The solution to this would be to keep a list of functions seen but the call stack size may still be inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this module:
https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js

Calling printStackTrace returns the stack trace inside an array, then you can check its length:

```
var trace = printStackTrace();
console.log(trace.length());
```

Comment: Best solution. Thanks fort this :D But I used this code instead:
require('stacktrace-js').getSync().length

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is measuring the available size on the stack in the top-level stack frame and then determining the used space on the stack by observing how much less space is available. In code:

```
function getRemainingStackSize()
{
    var i = 0;
    function stackSizeExplorer() {
        i++;
        stackSizeExplorer();
    }

    try {
        stackSizeExplorer();
    } catch (e) {
        return i;
    }
}

var baselineRemStackSize = getRemainingStackSize();
var largestSeenStackSize = 0;

function getStackSize()
{
    var sz = baselineRemStackSize - getRemainingStackSize();
    if (largestSeenStackSize < sz)
        largestSeenStackSize = sz;
    return sz;
}
```

For example:

```
function ackermann(m, n)
{
    if (m == 0) {
        console.log("Stack Size: " + getStackSize());
        return n + 1;
    }

    if (n == 0)
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1);

    return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n-1));
}

function main()
{
    var m, n;

    for (var m = 0; m < 4; m++)
    for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++)
        console.log("A(" + m + ", " + n + ") = " + ackermann(m, n));
    console.log("Deepest recursion: " + largestSeenStackSize + " (" +
            (baselineRemStackSize-largestSeenStackSize) + " left)");
}

main();
```

There are of course two major downsides to this approach:

(1) determining the used up stack space is a potentially an expensive operation when the VM has a large stack size and

(2) the numbers reported are not necessarily the number of recursions, but instead are a measurement of the actual space used on the stack (of course, this can also be an advantage). I've seen auto-generated code that contains functions that use the same space on the stack per recursion as 2000 recursions of the `stackSizeExplorer` function above.

Note: I have only tested the code above with node.js. But I assume it would work with all VMs that use a static stack size.